# Copy text from website

Tags: vb.net

So, I've been saving a .txt file from a website and using...

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText()
```

To put it into a string.
But I figured it'd be more efficient to just grab it directly.
How do I go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
Using wc As New WebClient()
    myString = wc.DownloadString(someUrl)
End Using
```

Comment: I realised my answer was a bad solution a few seconds after adding the answer, you must have added your comment just seconds before I deleted it :)

Comment: I changed DownloadText to DownloadString, as there dident seem to be a downloadText function, but there was a DownloadString function. And thanks! Just the answer I spent too long looking for.